# getbalances rpc call timeout

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, balance

I have a Bitcoin node having over 800K addresses. Recently I have been facing an issue with `getbalances` RPC call as it times out. I am using timeout as 100 seconds.
I can see that if I increase the timeout it may work but I am looking for any better other than this.

My question is:
Will use `getbalance "*" 1` will take less time than `getbalances`? I am more interested in getting the confirmed balance.

Or
Is there any alternate way i can get the wallet balance faster than afoementioned RPC calls?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no faster way to get the balance information, but there is ongoing work to change how the calculation is done so that it can run much faster. Currently, the balance is calculated by iterating all transactions in the wallet, so if you have a lot of tranasctions, it will spend a lot of time going through everything.

The only real suggestion that I have is to create a new wallet and send all of your coins to the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ava. Creating a new wallet is not applicable in my case.